# Private Beta invitation email error in footer

Tags: bug, status-completed, email, private-beta

I just received an invitation email to the private beta for Aviation.

The last line of the email is

> Questions? Comments? Let us know on our feedback site. If you no longer want to receive mail from $SiteNameLong, unsubscribe from all $SiteName emails with a single click.

Note the `$SiteNameLong` and `$SiteName`.

Comment: It's a do-it-yourself form letter. ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep, this one my my fault.  We had some fun translation things into Portuguese and missed a few key replacements.  Thanks for $verbing this issue and it has now been $verb.

Comment: This would be better with more madlibs